# Xcode Search Bar contains/filter

Tags: swift, xcode, filter

I have this function that filters my array if:

```
variable = "this"
Results = Results.filter({$0.(description == variable})
```

How do I filter by "contains"? I want to know if description has "this" in it.

If I search for "this" in my search bar it returns no results because description is "this is a description." NOT "this".

Thank you,

Denis Angell

Comment: Given that you have "variable" in quotes (as a String) I'm assuming that this is a Predicate?

Comment: No sorry, I actually edited the code in stack-exchange, I've edited the question.

Comment: Just updated my answer in response. Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's keep it simple and Swift-y:

```
variable = "this"
Results = Results.filter( { $0.description.contains(variable)})
```

Remember this tidbit

> Swift automatically provides shorthand argument names to inline closures, which can be used to refer to the values of the closure’s arguments by the names $0, $1, $2, and so on.

Hence, `$0` is nothing more than the first `Result` argument with property `description` of type `String`. This applies to all map, filter, and reduce operations.

Comment: Oh I see. Let me try this.